# Apache mod_setenvif Server_Addr

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an Apache server in a DMZ, reachaable on the LAN from 192.168.1.1, public 123.456.789.123.  I'm trying to get it to require authentication if the inbound hits are coming from the public side.   This doesn't seem to work:

SetEnvIf SERVER_ADDR 123.456.789.123 local_nic=1

```
<Location /junk>
  Order Deny,Allow
  AuthName "Access required"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, HTML tags were wiping out my Apache directives.

Comment: i guess something got lost in the formatting there, you are setting an env var but not doing anything with it later?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I found an easier way: require auth, allow 10.x.x.x, and Satisfy Any.  That lets people on the LAN get in without passwords, and people on the WAN to require passwords.